# Font Customization in bot framework web chat v4

Tags: javascript, html, css, botframework, web-chat

I am using web chat v4, I have created one dropdown there user can select font size/font weight for her/his convenience. I can't achieve two things.

- Can't change font size/font weight/font family for adaptive card/hero card/other attachments
- Can't change font family

I am currently using jquery to perform button click change  using id "webchat".Code is below. Similarly for font-weight, Help me achieve the two thing I mentioned.

```
function font_size() {
    var e = document.getElementById("sizeselect");
    var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("webchat").style.fontSize = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make changes to Adaptive Cards, you will actually need to edit and provide your own Host Config with your styling adjustments. You can take a look at [the Host Config editor](https://adaptivecards.io/visualizer/index.html?hostApp=Bot%20Framework%20WebChat) on AdaptiveCards.io to see the kinds of changes you are able to make.

Web Chat has its own [adaptiveCardHostConfig](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/component/src/Styles/adaptiveCardHostConfig.js) in use. You can use this page as an example on how to implement your own host config and use it in your version of Web Chat when you build your [`Composer`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/component/src/Composer.js#L276).